# Trigger spreadsheet script after change by IFTTT

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ifttt

Is there a way to make a google spreadsheet script run if the sheet is edited by IFTTT instead of by a person via the sheets browser?

Background: IFTTT put a value in a specific cell. My google spreadsheet script says if the cell is not empty; insert a new row. So my script is running if my sheet is edited by me manually and I put a value in that cell. However, if IFTTT adds a new entry to the spreadsheet nothing happens. I have tried both the onEdit and onChange triggers to no avail.  Any suggestions?

The actual script I am using is below:

```
(function InsertRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Diagramm');
  var values = sheet.getRange('B2').getValues();

  if (values[0][0] != "")
      sheet.insertRowBefore(2);

})();
```

So I followed [the tutorial on Google Driver API Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/apps-script) and added following code to my script:

```
function listFiles() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    maxResults: 10
  };
  var response = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs);
  var files = response.items;
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Files:');
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', file.title, file.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No files found.');
  }
};
```

But what do I need to do now? Sorry I am not a good programmer...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Drive API push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) to pick up these changes.

This example on [using Apps Script with the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/apps-script) is helpful to get started.

[Spencer Easton has also provided a tutorial on get GMail push notifications](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Gmail-Push-Notifications-v2) that'll give you some hints on setting this up as you have to make some changes in the dev console.

Comment: I followed this example and added the code in my script (more information in my first post). But can you help me what I have to do now? :)

Comment: I'm afraid it's quite involved and took me a while to work out, probably not the best project to start your programming career on - sorry.